# Memory Channels

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, allocation

### Problem(Background):

I am targeting a machine with four memory channels and a pcie card to and from which I want to stream data as fast as possible. Considering that the card can theoretically transfer approximately 8GB/s(7.88GB/s) each way, this would result in a throughput of approximately 15.8GB/s. Looking at [this](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/performance-chipsets/x79-express-chipset.html) I know that my maximum memory transfer rate is 12.8GB/s. Even without taking into account the actually installed memory it becomes obvious that the PCIe throughput exceeds what one memory channel can do.

To circumvent this I would like to ensure that the memory Block I stream to the device ends up on a different channel than the one I receive.

### Question

1. Is it possible to allocate memory on specific channels in the linux kernel and if so what is the interface to be used?
2. Is there anyway to obtain information about the mapping of physicall memory onto the different channels (Which addressranges/pageframes are on which channel)?
3. Is there an interface to request that a page is moved to/allocated on a specific frame?
4. How can I ensure that the page gets pinned before it gets swapped out/relocated? (Assuming I have to do `magic_allocate_page_on_channel(); get_user_pages(...)` I would have a short moment where the page could (theoretically) be swapped out again, and might get swapped to a differnet frame by `get_user_pages`)

Comment: take a look at https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596005903/ch15.html